# Do the heavier elements have a greater affinity for neutron capture and is there a theoretical maximum that can be captured?

Tags: nuclear-physics, neutrons

This question came to mind while reading about  Otto Hahn, Lise Meitner, Fritz Strassmann on the one hand and Seaborg on the other. A natural question ...what is the maximum theoretical transuranic element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question does not have a clear answer.

You probably address the superheavy elements problem (SHE). For the moment (imho), all observed superheavies decay by alpha particle decay. So there are two hunts -

- hunt for heavier and heavier superheavy element - can they exist?
- hunt for a (quasi-)stable superheavy element

The stability depends very much on the nuclear structure and **the structure  predictions depend on the models**. There are models, that predict island of stability somewhere but until experimentally confirmed, nobody can tell about the validity of different models. This is really a terra incognita for nuclear models.

This is one of the current topics in nuclear physics. Look at the http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1402-4896/aa53c1 e.g. This guy - Oganesian, has even an element named after him. Very unusual.

[image]